# Is there any way to achieve anonymized email?

Tags: email, smtp

I want to implement communication feature similar to Airbnb where real email address of both sender and receiver are hidden. For example if a sender has an email address `john@gmail.com` and the receiver's email is `smith@gmail.com` then when communication between them occurs using email then their real email address should be hidden and some other randomly generated email such as `info@xyz.com` for each of them should be displayed. Is there any way I can achieve this?

When John sends email to Smith then Smith should see something like `xyz@info.com` as the sender of email when Smith receives the mail in his corresponding email server such as Google, Yahoo, etc. And when Smith replies to the email then John should also see something like `abc@info.com` as the email of sender.

How is this possible in Java? Can it be achieved using Java JMS? Suppose the email server is Google then when the email is received from some random email like `abc@info.com` then how it is possible to reply the mail to the sender's actual email without revealing the actual email address?

It would be great if anyone can add some code snippet for this.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. And like airbnb, the only way to do this is to run a mail server. Then, you generate 2 long random strings, and store in the DB what they are masquerading:

```
Token             | Real mail
-----------------------------
quxpzo1mak        | john@gmail.com
ddi2mla12m        | smith@gmail.com
```

you send an email from yourmailserver.com to 'john@gmail.com' with from address 'ddi2mla12m@yourmailserver.com'. If john replies, then this mail will be received by you (its going to an address at your mailserver, and you can configure it in catchall mode, routing all traffic to some software under your control / to a mailbox, and your software IMAPs into it to read these). That software notices a mail coming from 'john@gmail.com' and addressed to 'ddi2mla12m', and thus, it then SENDS an email to 'smith@gmail.com' (you looked up ddi2mla12m to figure that out), and you mask the from, therefore, the sender is 'quxpzo1mak@gmail.com'.

If smith then replies to this, the same thing happens again in reverse.

Then you have to take anti-spam and such into consideration.

This is a complex undertaking, but that's how airbnb does it, and I don't think there's any other way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

The part behind the `@` is interesting for you. That should be **your** webserver which can handle smtp requests. (`gmail.com` is nothing more than a/multiple mailserver run by google under this DNS-address)

You'd then have a database (doesn't really have to be one though) mapping of `<real-email>` to `<generated-email>`. Something like:

```
<real-email>    | <generated-email>
john@gmail.com  | foo@example.com
smith@gmail.com | bar@example.com
```

Where `example.com` would be the the address of your mailserver

You would then have to forward any incoming email from:

```
Sender:   <real-sender-email>
Receiver: <generated-receiver-email>
```

To:

```
Sender:   <generated-sender-email>
Receiver: <real-receiver-email>
```